# VB.Net Encryption Function Not Decrypting Without Using Base64Encode

Tags: vb.net, string, byte

I am having a issue with decrypting, my goal is to be able to encrypt/decrypt with/without base64 encoding on the encrypted string. As of now I can encrypt/decrypt with base64 and encrypt without it but not decrypt without it. I get errors regarding the padding being incorrect.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my encryption/decryption function:

```
Public Function DoCryptWork(Type As String, Data As String) As String

    Dim Pass As String = Hasher.TextBoxPassword.Text
    Dim Salt As String = Hasher.TextBoxSalt.Text
    Dim Vect As String = Hasher.TextBoxIntVector.Text

    Select Case Type

        Case "e"

            Try

                Dim PassPhrase As String = Pass
                Dim SaltValue As String = Salt
                Dim HashAlgorithm As String = My.Settings.HashAlgorithm
                Dim PasswordIterations As Integer = 2
                Dim InitVector As String = Vect
                Dim KeySize As Integer = 256
                Dim InitVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitVector)
                Dim SaltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltValue)
                Dim PlainTextBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data)
                Dim Password As New PasswordDeriveBytes(PassPhrase, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations)
                Dim KeyBytes As Byte() = Password.GetBytes(KeySize \ 8)
                Dim SymmetricKey As New RijndaelManaged()

                SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

                Dim Encryptor As ICryptoTransform = SymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitVectorBytes)
                Dim MemoryStream As New MemoryStream()
                Dim CryptoStream As New CryptoStream(MemoryStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

                CryptoStream.Write(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length)
                CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()

                Dim CipherTextBytes As Byte() = MemoryStream.ToArray()

                MemoryStream.Close()
                CryptoStream.Close()

                Dim CipherText As String = Nothing

                If My.Settings.Base64EncodeMD5Hash = True Then

                    CipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(CipherTextBytes)

                    Return CipherText

                Else

                    Dim TextCipher As New StringBuilder()

                    For n As Integer = 0 To CipherTextBytes.Length - 1

                        TextCipher.Append(CipherTextBytes(n).ToString("X2"))

                    Next n

                    CipherText = TextCipher.ToString()

                    Return CipherText

                End If

            Catch ex As Exception

                MsgBox("Encryption was unsuccessfull!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

                Return "Encryption was unsuccessfull!"

            End Try

        Case "d"

            Try

                Dim PassPhrase As String = Pass
                Dim SaltValue As String = Salt
                Dim HashAlgorithm As String = My.Settings.HashAlgorithm
                Dim PasswordIterations As Integer = 2
                Dim InitVector As String = Vect
                Dim KeySize As Integer = 256
                Dim InitVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitVector)
                Dim SaltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltValue)
                Dim CipherTextBytes As Byte() = Nothing

                If My.Settings.Base64EncodeMD5Hash = True Then

                    CipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Data)

                Else

                    Dim bytedata As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data)

                    CipherTextBytes = bytedata

                End If

                Dim Password As New PasswordDeriveBytes(PassPhrase, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations)
                Dim KeyBytes As Byte() = Password.GetBytes(KeySize \ 8)
                Dim SymmetricKey As New RijndaelManaged()

                SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

                Dim Decryptor As ICryptoTransform = SymmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(KeyBytes, InitVectorBytes)
                Dim MemoryStream As New MemoryStream(CipherTextBytes)
                Dim CryptoStream As New CryptoStream(MemoryStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Dim PlainTextBytes As Byte() = New Byte(CipherTextBytes.Length - 1) {}
                Dim DecryptedByteCount As Integer = CryptoStream.Read(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length)

                MemoryStream.Close()
                CryptoStream.Close()

                Dim PlainText As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PlainTextBytes, 0, DecryptedByteCount)

                Return PlainText

            Catch Ex As Exception

                MsgBox("Decryption was unsuccessfull!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Ex.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

                Return "Decryption was unsuccessfull!"

            End Try

        Case Else

            Return "Error! Invalid Case Selected  We should never see this but just to be safe we'll show this message if the wrong case is selected!"

    End Select

    Return True

End Function
```

I call the function as so:

```
TextBoxOutput.Text = Encryption.DoCryptWork("e", TextBoxInput.Text) ' encrypt data.
TextBoxOutput.Text = Encryption.DoCryptWork("d", TextBoxInput.Text) ' decrypt data.
```

Comment: _"but decryption fails."_ - Could you elaborate that? Any error messages? -- Also, have you tried stepping through your code using a debugger?

Comment: I get a padding is invalid error. I am debugging as we speak but have not found anything as of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert the bytes to hex, you output two hex digits per byte. When you convert that hex back to bytes, you're converting every hex digit to a byte instead of every pair of hex digits.

Actually, I just took another look and noticed that you're not even keeping the earlier bytes.  This loop:

```
For n As Integer = 0 To Data.Length - 1
    CipherTextBytes = Convert.ToByte(Data(n))
Next n
```

sets `CipherTextBytes` on each iteration so you're going to replace the previous byte each time, so you only end up keeping the byte from the last digit.

Comment: Thanks! @jmcilhinney Worked out Great!

Comment: Hi again! I thought I had it working turns out I did  in fact not. I put up the whole function so that you may better understand my goal in the end. If you can have another look that would be awesome! Same issue as before. Thanks again, Jason